# Can't send POST request with body using cypress

Tags: api, cypress

Can't send a request with the body. If i'm adding `form: true` then i'm receiving an error 500

```
"details": "Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

but if i don't add then request doesn't see body keys

IMAGE_CODE

[image: 1]

IMAGE_ERROR

[image: 2]

```
            cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'token',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>'
            },
            form: true,
            body: {
                "uploadRequest": {
                    "fileType": "type",
                    "description": "other"
                },
            }
        })
    })



Body: {
"httpStatusCode": 500,
"errors": [
{
"code": "1001",
"description": "A service exception has occurred",
"details": "Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
```

Comment: Hi. At first look, is not related to your code. I do suspect it happens because your app controller can't handle the `multipart/form-data` header. Try removing/comment this header and run your request again.

Comment: @AlexIzbas the same..(

Comment: @djkjlz1. Please post the code  and error as text not an images

Comment: All 2 images too.

Comment: By see the error message, I guess the problem is from your body. Please check your body is 'multipart/form-data' type